# DNS for guest VMs

Tags: centos, dns, dhcp, vmware-workstation

On my Windows 10 pc (host) i have installed couple of guest VMs. The router provides dhcp and dns services to the host. If i want to configure DNS server on one of the guest VMs which would act as the DNS server for the other gues VMs only, would it interrupt the internet connectivity of my guest VMs via the NAT interface i have configured for them? OR would the DNS/DHCP services of the router to the host be interrupted?

Current VM interface configuration:

1. NAT interface ens33, IP-192.168.33.128. vmnet1 on host - 192.168.33.1
2. Host only interface ens37, IP-192.168.242.128. vmnet2 on host - 192.168.220.1

Answer (score 1):

Having several different DNS servers is not a problem: each client host will use whatever DNS server(s) configured for them and no others. This configuration can happen manually or by DHCP.

If your guest VMs get their IP parameters from the router's DHCP server, then you would have to either override the DNS server settings in the guest VMs' network settings, or to have the router send differente DNS server settings for those guest VMs (if possible - the DHCP configuration interface in non-enterprise routers tends to be quite limited).

Answer (score 1):

Using different DNS servers will not affect internet connectivity on its own, but may affect reaching certain things depending on the configuration of this VM DNS server.

Do note that computers only use the response from the first DNS server in its configuration that responds (even if the response is a "not found"). Another way to word this is: Computers will only fall back to another DNS server if the prior DNS server didn't respond at all (time-out, unreachable, etc).

Comment: If my answer was helpful, could you give it an upvote, and if it answered your question, mark it as such? Thank you!